# How to check when the file was deleted using tortoisesvn in Windows 7?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

A file is deleted from **SVN**. How can We check that in which revision it was deleted using **tortoisesvn** in *Windows 7*?

Answer (score 0):

**TortoiseSVN:**

1. Start TortoiseSVN's [Revision Log Dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html),
2. [Filter log messages](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-filter). For example, enter the name of the deleted file.
   First or one of the first revisions should show the revision where the file was removed.

**Subversion 1.8+ command-line client:**

Run [`svn log` command with `--search`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search) option:
`svn log --search FILENAME <URL>`.

Comment: You did not mention it, but I'll just chip in. Setting the range with dates and revisions seems to be bugged for deleted files in TortoiseSVN 1.7. Should install the latest version, or at least the latest 1.8.x version.

Comment: @Dialecticus I don't remember anything about such bug in TortoiseSVN. Do you have any reference? Nevertheless, with the release of Subversion 1.9, Subversion 1.7 is now *out of support*. The supported SVN versions are now 1.8 and the newest 1.9.

Comment: Sorry, no reference apart from what I've seen. In 1.7 I selected old revision in the log, and then right-clicked on a file that was deleted afterwards, and selected "Show log" in the menu. Tortoise got confused, and couldn't show me the log for just that file. The same operation works fine in the latest Tortoise version.

Comment: @bahrep I opened **Revision Log Dialog** and searched the deleted file but could not find that. I am using version *1.8.7* of **tortoisesvn**.

Comment: @Varun paths in Subversion are *case-sensitive*. Make sure that you enter correct name of file.

Comment: I am checking that search is not *case sensitive*. Although I tried by writing same file but it can not find it.

Comment: @Varun what happens if you enter a file name that is certainly there?

Comment: @Dialecticus When I write name of deleted file it does not show any file in the box in which revsion no. and messages are shown.

Comment: When I was searching file name in the parent folder of deleted file it was showing nothing, But when I searched the file in logs at project level I can see *Added* and *Modified* logs of that file but can not see *Deleted* logs of that file.